# jquery load a specific #Div content from multiple html files

Tags: php, jquery, function, load

I am trying to make a Content Slider for my site. I have multiple HTML files and the structure of these files is like this:

```
<div id="title"><h2>Title of the Slide</h2></div>
<div id="image"><a href="http://mylink.com"><img src="image.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="image"</a></div>
<div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</div>
```

I have been trying to use the following script get content **(but no success)**:

```
<?php
function render($position="") {
    ob_start();
    foreach(glob("/slides/*.html") as $fileName) {
    $fname = basename( $fileName );
    $curArr = file($fname);
    $slides[$fname ]['title'] = $curArr[0];
    $slides[$fname ]['image'] = $curArr[1];
    $slides[$fname ]['content'] = $curArr[2];

    foreach($slides as $key => $value){

        ?>
          <div id="slide-title">
            <?php echo $value['title'] ?>
          </div>

          <div id="slide-content">
              <?php echo $value['content'] ?>
          </div>

          <div id="slide-image">
              <?php echo $value['image'] ?>
          </div>

        <?php
        }}
        ?>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

But then I came to know about a jQuery function.... (again no success)

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
      (function($){
        $(document).ready(function () {    
          $('#slide-title').load('slides/slide1.html #title');
          $('#slide-content').load('slides/slide1.html #content');
          $('#slide-image').load('slides/slide1.html #image');
      });   
    })(jQuery);
```

Now My questions are.....

1. Am I using the right syntax.
2. How do I get the content from multiple files using jQuery.

***Please Note :*** My knowledge on Programming is almost '0'. I have just started learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has no intuitive knowledge of files on the remote file system. You could, however, do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
      for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        $('body').append('<div id="slide-content-'+i+'"></div>');
        $('#slide-title-'+i).load('slides/slide'+i+'.html #title');
        // ...and so on
      }
});
```

This will do something akin to what you were trying to do with PHP. I don't know PHP very well but that could be a better way to go (depending on it's DOM processing abilities) since the above will create one request for each file.

Comment: Hey @Josh thanks for the post but that is not the issue. I think you missed the point.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP is passing the jQuery object into the closure, so can use $ without problems

Comment: Missed that. My bad. Revised answer.

Comment: @josh It is showing Syntax Error in 2nd line. Kindly correct the code. I will not be able to provide you more info as I don't know JavaScript at all. I am just a copy paster,

Comment: @Vikram, fixed the typo. Getting my languages crossed.

Comment: Hey @josh. Thanks for the correction. Now it worked. Thanks a lot Gos bless you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#slide-title').load('slides/slide1.html #title');
$('#slide-content').load('slides/slide1.html #content');
$('#slide-title').load('slides/slide1.html #image');
```

This will work, but not very quickly. You are doing three separate requests to the same page. You can combine them all into one fairly easily using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and its callback argument:

```
$.get('slides/slide1.html', function(html) {
    var $html = $(html);

    $('#slide-title').html($html.find('#title'));
    $('#slide-content').html($html.find('#content'));
    $('#slide-image').html($html.find('#image'));
});
```

Note that I have corrected `slide-title` to `slide-image` in the last line, since I hink that's what you need.

Comment: Wow thanks for the post. Just one more question..... How do I get the loop from multiple files. I mean this should read all the files from that folder (slides) and from each file it should get the title, image content and assign them to their respective divs.

Comment: @Vikram You can use that code multiple times with different URLs and different element IDs. It's difficult to guess exactly what you want to do. One big problem, looking at your PHP code is that you have multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid and won't work. Please provide your rendered HTML if you want to do this with Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Your jquery code seems to be correct.  What is the output you are getting?

Here's a pointer to what you are trying to accomplish..

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-select-element/

Let me know whether this helps....

Comment: Hey @Rajesh, Thanks for the pointer but then that is not the issue. I want to know how do I get the content from multiple files in a loop?

Comment: Oh ok...I thought the jquery selector was not loading up the content...I have newbie in PHP so, will wait for someone else to answer this :)